# understanding composer require & its remote location

Tags: composer-php, magento2

i have this in composer.json and i am trying to undersntad which file it is pulling. its tinipng magento extension code

i can understand that its requesting version greater than 1.5 and here in github i can see version 1.5.2 but github link how it is added. its not just github.com/tinify/tinify

https://github.com/tinify/tinify-php/releases/tag/1.5.2

so magento is pulling require field from some other place or some link in require field ??

```
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "tinify/tinify": ">=1.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry. coposer documentation is right place. 
this question all answers are in https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md

got the answer